# How to remove the entire ubuntu-desktop package?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt, package-management

I use linux Mint 18 cinnamon. While I am working I always have a lot of different softwares running and I wanted to try Unity to see if the left-side bar would be more confortable. So, as I found written on the internet, I installed `ubuntu-desktop`. This package installed on my computer a lot of other packages like `nautilus`, etc.. How can I remove all the packages that I downloaded with `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: You could try `apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop` and then afterwards a `apt-get autoremove` which then should remove all packages that were not explicitly installed.